# Sorting Divs with JS or Jquery based on inner div text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm attempting to sort a class of divs inside of a div container called `#searchResultsWrapper`. I know that the elements I'm referring to in my sort function are correct and are integers. I'm just unsure why it won't work.

```
var sortedResults = $('#searchResultsWrapper').children().sort(function(a,b){
    if(a.getElementsByClassName('searchResultKeywordCount')[0].innerHTML < b.getElementsByClassName('searchResultKeywordCount')[0].innerHTML)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
});
    
$('#searchResultsWrapper').empty();
$('#searchResultsWrapper').append(sortedResults);
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="searchResultsWrapper">
  <div class="searchResultWrapper">
    <div class="searchResultMenuBar">
      <div class="searchResultMenuBarAddButton"></div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="searchResultHeading">some doc heading</h1>
    <div class="searchResultTextWrapper">
      <div class="searchResultText">
        some text
      </div>
      <div class="searchResultKeywordCount">
        5
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="searchResultWrapper">
    <div class="searchResultMenuBar">
      <div class="searchResultMenuBarAddButton"></div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="searchResultHeading">some doc heading</h1>
    <div class="searchResultTextWrapper">
      <div class="searchResultText">
        some text
      </div>
      <div class="searchResultKeywordCount">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was expecting the list of divs to be rearranged based on a hidden div I have in a `.searchResult` child class called `.searchResultKeywordCount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you need to take care of:

- `.innerHTML` will return you a string, so you will need to convert it to number. You can use `Number()` for that
- `.innerHTML` can have white space which can give unwanted issues. You will have to trim it before conversion.

When you are manipulating DOM elements in loop, its better to look into [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment). This is an optimisation technique as mutation of DOM element will trigger repaint and reflow

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('searchResultsWrapper')
const allDivs = parent.querySelectorAll('.searchResultWrapper')
const fragment = new DocumentFragment()
const getInnerValue = (div) => Number(
  div.querySelector('.searchResultKeywordCount').innerText.trim()
)

Array
  .from(allDivs)
  .sort((a, b) => getInnerValue(a) - getInnerValue(b))
  .forEach((elm) => fragment.append(elm))

parent.innerHTML = ''
parent.append(fragment)
```

```html
<div id="searchResultsWrapper">
  <div class="searchResultWrapper">
    <div class="searchResultMenuBar">
      <div class="searchResultMenuBarAddButton"></div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="searchResultHeading">some doc heading</h1>
    <div class="searchResultTextWrapper">
      <div class="searchResultText">
        some text
      </div>
      <div class="searchResultKeywordCount">
        5
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="searchResultWrapper">
    <div class="searchResultMenuBar">
      <div class="searchResultMenuBarAddButton"></div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="searchResultHeading">some doc heading</h1>
    <div class="searchResultTextWrapper">
      <div class="searchResultText">
        some text
      </div>
      <div class="searchResultKeywordCount">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough answer. This did exactly what I needed, but in reverse so I just switched a and b.